# Radius of Convergence of power series of Complex Analysis 111

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to find radius of convergence of this complex power series  $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {e^{in-2in^2}+in \over n^3+3^{in}}{(z+1-i)}^n$$
I tried ratio test and also Cauchy Hadamard but nothing seems to work. Maybe some hint about what to do with that exp would help. Thank you for your help

Comment: Voted to close because no effort is shown.

Comment: @avid19 - I'm not sure that is reason to close. But I would recommend that the asker does show his/her progress for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Well the OP said ratio and Cauchy Hadamard were attempted; I think closing is a bit harsh here.

Comment: Hint: Compare the absolute value of those coefficients with $1/n^2.$

Comment: thanks but still do not know how to continue

Comment: I made a mistake-I did not want to comment on this question. I am trying to respond to my own question and got here by mistake. So delete this please!!